Android accessibility: perform an accessibility action without moving the cursor in WebView
I'm developing an Android accessibility application.
for this application I need to retrieve the five nodes immediately following the node currently focused by talkback (the five nodes that talkback will focus on)
I've tried using the focusSearch function:
AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat focusSearch(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat node, int direction)

but it sometimes returns nodes that aren't focused by talkback.
I've noticed that when I use the function:
AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.performAction(int action, Bundle arguments)

it always find the right nodes except that the cursor moves too.
I don't know if there's a way to perform an accessibilty action without moving the cursor, or if there is an approach that correctly returns the nodes we're looking for.
